# What is a manifold quotient that is "almost everywhere" a manifold.

Tags: riemannian-geometry, quotient-spaces

Edit: There has been some confusion with the construction below. I think My question can be summarized as:

**"How do I characterize a manifold quotient whose group action in not finite?"**

Original construction:
I start with the hyperbolic disc $\mathbb{H}^2$ and partition the boundary into 4 sets of equal length $\{A_i\}=\{A,B,C,D\}$. Choosing to parameterize the boundary by an angular coordinate $\phi$ I have $A=(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, $B=(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi)$... etc.  Call the geodesic with endpoints on $\partial A_{i}$, $m(A_i)$. By symmetry each $m(A_i)$ has the same shape and length.

Now suppose I define the equivalence relation $\sim: \; m(A)\sim m(B) \sim m(C) \sim m(D)$ and define the quotient space $ Q \equiv \mathbb{H}^2 \setminus \sim$. This has the effect of creating 4 sheets, one for each  region of the manifold between $A_i$ and $m(A_i)$ which I call $r(A_i)$. These meet at the common locus $m$. Notably this removes the interior region $\mathbb{H}^2 \setminus \cup_i r(A_i)$.

What is the correct way mathematically to describe $Q$? It's not a manifold, but each leaf can inherit the metric and coordinate charts from $\mathbb{H}^2$ except on $m$. Even so $m$ has a well defined length. In this (imprecise) sense $Q$ is "almost" a manifold. Is there a more general theory of such objects?

[Original manifold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7bsp.jpg)

[Q after quotient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRgn1.jpg)

Edit: For reference the construction I'm interested in can be viewed as a generalization of pg.7 fig.1 of [1406.2663](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2663.pdf#page=8). The distinction being I am interested in the case when more than 2 geodesics of the same length are identified.

Comment: I am sorry, but none of this makes sense, starting with the first sentence.

Comment: Care to elaborate? I'm happy to reword the construction.

Comment: Start with the first sentence: What means equal? How are they supposed to meet at the right angle? (Totally is impossible  afaiak.) What are the $A_i$'s? In which sense minimal?.....

Comment: I did my best to reword things based on your suggestions. Hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: I'm also having trouble making sense of the question, but it seems that what you are referring to is a manifold with [singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_theory).

Comment: If I understand your construction correctly, you end up with 4 sheets, which are glued together along $m$, right? If this is correct: your resulting space is not a manifold, because it is not locally homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ on $m$. One related thing I can think of is the theory of [orbifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbifold), but you cannot use it directly, because (if I understand your construction correctly) you are not taking a quotient wrt a finite group.

Comment: This is right. I think my question can be reworded as "How do I characterize a manifold quotient whose group action in not finite?". I've seen the term "stratifold". Is this an accurate classification?

Comment: I still do not understand. When you say "geodesic" do you mean hyperbolic or Euclidean geodesic? Your equivalence relation is not well-defined since you did not explain how do you match points of $m(A_i)'s: If you do this via a hyperbolic isometry, there is a continuum of such. Do you care which one to take? I think though, I know what are you getting: one name of this object is "hyperbolic polygonal complex," they are discussed in various places, for instance in the book by Bridson and Haefliger.